# How to include files from other project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, database-project

We have two projects in `visual studio`, first one is workflows which generated `sql` files by a `DSL tool` (this is something like `Linq2Sql designer` which gestates files automatically by every change)
Second one is a `Database` project, 
I want to include the generated `sql` files in database project, so that when the content regenerated, I wouldn't need to copy paste it in database project.

For this reason, I add existing `sql` files as Link (`Add as link`) to database project, the problem is they don't copy in build process, then I get an error about files are not exists.

I found an article about it in http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx but that one is not working for me too.

Then I was thinking about including files automatically in my solution by adding something like , but they will be added to the root of the project not in the desired path.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\..\Workflows\*.sql" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833213(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Your solution is appropriate, you can write it as answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. If there is a better solution, you can mark it. Thanks.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT done man

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue, but I keep it open to get better solutions

I added below code to project file

```
<Content Include="..\..\Workflows\*.sql">
  <Link>Deployment\Post-Deployment\WorkflowDataSync\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

And I added this to `pre-build event command line` in project properties page

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\Workflows\*.sql" "$(ProjectDir)Deployment\Post-Deployment\WorkflowDataSync" /Y /I
```